# UIScrollView is not passing touches to subviews in iOS8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, ios8

I've tested the same code I'm using now in iOS7 and it works fine, but in iOS8 my scrollview appears to not be passing touch events to subviews. I have a view structure like this:

```
- UIScrollView
   - UIView
       - buttonView
```

I've subclassed each of the above views and added the `touchesBegan:`, `touchesCancelled:`, `touchesShouldCancelInContentView`,  `touchesShouldBegin:` methods to each and the only view that ever registers anything is the `UIScrollView`. Also the only method that executes on the `UIScrollView` subclass is `touchesBegan:`. No other delegate methods are fired. This didn't happen in iOS7 with the same code, but it's happening now in iOS8. Can anyone tell me what may have changed that would cause this behavior or even better a fix. I've looked at many posts on this topic, but the standard answers have not done anything.

I've tried changing `delaysContentTouches` and `CancellableContentTouches` to no avail.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe you could post some code to determine the issue? 
Are you sure your scrollView's `contentSize` is set to large enough?